# Flutter pub get takes too long to execute

Tags: flutter

When running a new application  "flutter pub get" in Vscode keeps running without completion.I have tried flutter clean , and reopening vscode.

Comment: Have you tried it directly in the command line, outside of VS Code?

Comment: I tried that but same issue occurs again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to check the proper package name. Maybe you misspelled the package name or else your internet is not working fine.

Comment: It is running on Linux and Windows but im getting this issue on macOs Catalina.

Comment: I think macOS have some proxy issue then, try to find out that some proxy related thing is blocking you to download the package or not. Also try to change the WIFI network sometime it also help you :)

Comment: When I switched to my phone hotspot, it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Try `flutter clean` command, remove `pubspec.lock` file in root directory then re-run `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue, I checked all package names, they were correct. I did run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` and it's worked. Hope! this might be helpful if some one faces same issue as I was.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: **flutter clean**
step 2: **remove pubspec.lock**
step 3: If your project has lots of dependencies then load 1 or 2 at once .

It can happen because of lots of dependencies and slow internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would be the issue related to the network rules in your system. means issue is related to IT team. they will unblock your firewall or use network proxy to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While my normal internet connection took more than 15 minutes, I connected to vpn from a different country and tried `flutter pub get`. It worked pretty fast.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30904485)

Comment: I had the same issue, and I posted what worked for me. I tried all answers posted before, but this is what solved it. It may not be the case for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I resolved it by synchronizing date and hours of my computer.
With an incorrect date, you can have some network issues.

(My computer's date was set to 'yesterday')

Answer (score 0):

## Changing the pub endpoint to China's one

for some reason, the default endpoint takes too much time to respond so changing the pub. dev endpoint might help

### On Linux or Mac OSX, this worked for me and many other people...

edit `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` based on your shell

```bash
export PUB_HOSTED_URL="https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL="https://storage.flutter-io.cn"
```

run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` to apply the changes to the current terminal window.

### On Windows, you should create an environment variable with the following:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| PUB_HOSTED_URL | https://pub.flutter-io.cn |
| FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL | https://storage.flutter-io.cn |

*Code got from MathiasGodwin on Grepper*

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected from the VPN and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I connected via VPN. And run flutter pub get. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

just use different internet, for my case, i used my phone's data mobile hotpost to fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).