# How can i solve this pub deprecated pub

Tags: flutter, dart

pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOjB2.png)
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
"PUB_CACHE": "C:\U[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF4rJ.png)sers\BOSS-PRYME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}

Comment: When you got this error? While trying to execute flutter pub get?

Comment: Please provide with screenshot of the error and flutter doctor result

Comment: @JakhongirAnasov Anasov Anasov I get this error when i execute flutter pub get.

Comment: @JakhongirAnasov i get those errors when i want to use a package.

Comment: The reason can be http host unavailabiity which is shown in flutter doctor report. Try to fix it. Use vpn , etc. It may resolve your problem.

Comment: Great. I am happy for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, this worked for me and for many other people...
It should work for you too.
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn

On windows, you should create an environment variable with:
name: PUB_HOSTED_URL value: https://pub.flutter-io.cn

name: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL value: https://storage.flutter-io.cn

#Code gotten from MathiasGodwin on Grepper

This answer came from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588402/flutter-pub-get-takes-too-long-to-execute#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20flutter%20clean%20step,dependencies%20and%20slow%20internet%20connection.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588402/flutter-pub-get-takes-too-long-to-execute#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20flutter%20clean%20step,dependencies%20and%20slow%20internet%20connection.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was facing this error because my dart version was lower than my project requirement in pubspec.yaml, I changed my project version to match that of my dart sdk